# Whole Website moving left on iPhone when swiping - how does one turn that off?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

When I open the website http://www.stuttmann-karikaturen.de/karikatur/6358 in Chrome, make the **browser window as narrow as possible** and then swipe the image to the left with the mouse, **everything works as it should - the title stays in the center** and the image moves:

[image: In Chrome with window made small]

If I switch to **iPhone 6** view mode and do the same, the **title moves to the left** as well (just as it does on a real iPhone):

[image: In Chrome in iPhone 6 mode]

I don't know enough CSS to find the reason behind that (I didn't write it, that's my excuse).

I checked if on of the containing elements (1, 2 in image below) is too wide, but as far as I can tell it fits the phone width exactly (both are set to 375, matching the width of the iPhone view in Chrome) (3):
[image: Container widths]

So it seems that neither

```
<div id="container">
```

nor

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

are responsible. I guess there is a difference between the behavior of swiping in a small browser window and the one in an iPhone. How can I turn that off?

**Additional note:** the owl-carousel is just to add this gallery functionality to jQuery. I did not post additional code because (a) the issue is visible online and (b) there's a lot code involved that could be responsible so I post it on request.

Comment: This might well not be the issue, but do you have a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tag in your `head`? If not, try adding that.

Comment: @JoeClay - almost - I have "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to make a

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

on the body, it will fix your problem.

This bug is present because image width in your slider is too large

Comment: OMG - thanks a lot. I am shocked how embarrassingly simple that was.

Comment: @Olaf no problem